# PowerShell Restart services if SQL statement returns value

Tags: powershell

I want to restart windows service, but only when my SQL statement returns value. 
So I'm able to set `$SqlResult`, but I have problem with restarting services only when variable is set to "RUN".

These are the steps I want to perform:

```
Stop-Service -Name SERVICENAME
timeout.exe /t 10
taskkill.exe /F /IM KILLTASK.exe
Start-Service -Name SERVICENAME
```

I was thinking to do it with 'If' but probably I'm doing something wrong.

```
If ($SqlResult = "RUN")
{
    Stop-Service -Name SERVICENAME
    timeout.exe /t 10
    taskkill.exe /F /IM KILLTASK.exe
    Start-Service -Name SERVICENAME
}
```

I also try to use 'Switch' but with no success.

This is how it looks right now what I'm doing wrong?:

```
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=MYSERVER;Database=MYDataBase;Integrated Security=True"

$SqlConnection.Open()

$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "if exists ( MyQuery ) Select 'RUN' Else Select 'END'"
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection

$SqlResult = $SqlCmd.ExecuteScalar()
$SqlConnection.Close()

#$SqlResult = "RUN"
#Write-output $SqlResult

Switch ($SqlResult) {
    RUN {
        Stop-Service -Name SERVICENAME
        timeout.exe /t 10
        taskkill.exe /F /IM KILLTASK.exe
        Start-Service -Name SERVICENAME
    }
    END {
        Exit
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a single equal operator (`=`) which is used to assign something in PowerShell, not to compare something. You can do that with `-eq`:

```
If ($SqlResult -eq "RUN")
{
Stop-Service -Name SERVICENAME
timeout.exe /t 10
taskkill.exe /F /IM KILLTASK.exe
Start-Service -Name SERVICENAME
}
```